# Sorting from multiple nodes by alphanumeric format

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<accountList>
    <previousAccount>
        <account>
            <lastName>NASH</lastName>
            <accountStatus>REMOVED</accountStatus>
            <accNo>8D</accNo>
        </account>
        <account>
            <lastName>ADOGA</lastName>
            <accountStatus>REMOVED</accountStatus>
            <accNo>8A</accNo>
        </account>
        <account>
            <lastName>LUCAS</lastName>
            <accountStatus>HOLD</accountStatus>
            <accNo>9A</accNo>
        </account>
        <account>
            <lastName>DONALD</lastName>
            <accountStatus>HOLD</accountStatus>
            <accNo>10D</accNo>
        </account>
        <account>
            <accountStatus>HOLD</accountStatus>
            <lastName>LONDON</lastName>
            <accNo>10B</accNo>
        </account>
    </previousAccount>
    <account>
        <Title>Mr</Title>
        <firstName>RICHARD</firstName>
        <lastName>JOHN</lastName>
        <city>london</city>
        <accNo>5A</accNo>
    </account>
    <account>
        <Title>Mr</Title>
        <firstName>xxx</firstName>
        <lastName>JOHN</lastName>
        <city>London</city>
        <accNo>5D</accNo>
    </account>
    <account>
        <Title>Mr</Title>
        <firstName>HEWIT</firstName>
        <lastName>JOHN</lastName>
        <city>LONDON</city>
        <accNo>20B</accNo>
    </account>
    <account>
        <Title>Mr</Title>
        <firstName>xxx</firstName>
        <lastName>JOHN</lastName>
        <city>LONDON</city>
        <accNo>21D</accNo>
    </account>
    <account>
        <Title>Mr</Title>
        <firstName>KEVIN</firstName>
        <lastName>PETE</lastName>
        <city>LONDON</city>
        <accNo>5F</accNo>
    </account>
</accountList>
```

xslt code

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform file:/C:/Users/n434947/Desktop/workspace/SonicXSLT/BA xslt page.xsd"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:variable name="newline">
    <xsl:text>
    </xsl:text>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:template match="accountList">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="descendant::account" group-starting-with="*[firstName != 'xxx' or lastName != preceding-sibling::*[1]/lastName]">
        <xsl:sort select="accNo" data-type="number"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="accNo"/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="accountStatus"/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="lastName"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

In my requirement ,I got to sort accNo which are different nodes.I think I'll do much better explaining this in code rather than words,
    accountList/previousAccount/account/accNo
    accountList/account/accNo

I used descendant,which is not working fine for my requirement.Here I have used two for-each for two nodes and sorted separtedly.Last but not least I got to sort by alphanumeric combinations.

Actual Output

```
    8D REMOVED NASH
    8A REMOVED ADOGA
    9A HOLD LUCAS
    10D HOLD DONALD
    10B HOLD LONDON
    5A  JOHN
    20B  JOHN
    5F  PETE
```

Expecting output

```
    5A  JOHN
    5F  PETE
    8A REMOVED ADOGA
    8D REMOVED NASH
    9A HOLD LUCAS
    10B HOLD LONDON
    10D HOLD DONALD
    20B  JOHNaccNo will be in sorted manner.
```

The main problem is am unable sort by alphanumeric combinations like 2A,2B,3B,3G

Answer (score 1):

Well this is a dirty solution... use this function:

```
<xsl:function name="px:toInteger" as="xs:double">
    <xsl:param name="value" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:variable name="letter" select="replace($value, '\d', '')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="digit" select="xs:integer(replace($value, '\D', ''))" as="xs:integer"/>
    <xsl:variable name="codepoints" select="xs:integer(string-to-codepoints($letter))" as="xs:integer"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$digit + ($codepoints div 100000)"/>
</xsl:function>
```

and call it in the xsl:sort:

```
<xsl:sort select="px:toInteger(accNo)" data-type="number"/>
```

it just works for a Integer + one character like your samples.